# Remote controll via Mavlink with iNAV 3.0?

Tags: quadcopters, raspberry-pi, inav

I'm not that familiar with Mavlink, but try to find a way to controll my FC Omnibus F4 nano v5 via a serial connection to a RPI (which is itself connect to a wifi).

Using mavproxy, I'm able to establish a link via a UART. I need to setup iNAV to drive mavlink telemetry on that port. But of course mavproxy complains about missing RC command featureset.

Also enabling Serial RX with mavlink protocol on that UART is ignored. The team says [it don't work](https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav/issues/7092) on the same UART.
Has anybody experience if I need to split-up Mavlink RX/TX into two UARTs or how I can completely control and sense the drone just via mavlink?

Comment: The upcomming 4.x subversion will support sharing the same uart rx/tx for mavling https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav/pull/6738